# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't see wireless network

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04. The problem is that it cannot find a way to get a wireless connection. In **All Settings > Network** I see only **Wired** and **Network proxy**, so I guess Ubuntu does not recognize any wireless card or at least does not have the right drivers to use it properly.

Here is some information from the terminal:

`sudo lshw -class network:`

```
 *-network DISABLED
          description: Wireless interface   
           product: Wireless 7265        
           vendor: Intel Corporation   
           physical id: 0        
           bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
           logical name: wlo1
           version: 61
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi <   driverversion=4.8.0-36-generic firmware=22.361476.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
          resources: irq:281 memory:b1100000-b1101fff
```

**UPDATE**

```
$ rfkill list all

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

It works perfectly if I tether with USB, but it doesn't recognize any wifi connection. I have probably missed something.

Comment: *DISABLED* usually means that the wireless switch or key combination is set to turn the wireless radio off. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does `sudo ifconfig wl01 up` do anything for you?

Comment: @heynnema no, it says `w101: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device`

Comment: You typed the command incorrectly. The device name is wl01, not w101. wl stands for wireless. You can copy/paste it directly from my previous comment, if you like.

Comment: No, it still shows this message: `wl01: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device`

Comment: @chili555, I've updated my question.